# How to select multiple checkbox then store values in a list? python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()    

users = ['Anne', 'Bea', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Helen']
selected_users=[]

for x in range(len(users)):
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=users[x][0], variable=users[x])
    l.pack(anchor = 'w')

root.mainloop()
```

I have this sample code, I need to make multiple selections in that `users` list, after I hit `OK`, it stores checked value into another list named `selected_users` for later use.

For example, when I run this code, a checkbox window pops out, and I tick `Anne`,`Bob`, click `OK`. `selected_users` is now `['Anne','Bob']`. And Window disappears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()    
users = ['Anne', 'Bea', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Helen']
selected_users=[]
for x in range(len(users)):
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=users[x][0], variable=users[x],command=lambda x=users[x]:selected_users.append(x))
    l.pack(anchor = 'w')
Button(root,text="Ok",command=lambda: [print(selected_users),root.destroy()]).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This will add the value to the list and when you hit `Ok` the window will disappear.

Adding more functionality to the program:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()    
users = ['Anne', 'Bea', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Helen']
users_l=[str(i) for i in range(len(users))]
selected_users=[]
def add_remove(user,var):
    if var.get()==0:
        try:
            selected_users.remove(user)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    else:
        selected_users.append(user)
for x in range(len(users)):
    users_l[x]=IntVar(0)
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=users[x], variable=users_l[x],offvalue=0,onvalue=1,command=lambda x=users[x],y=users_l[x]:add_remove(x,y))
    l.pack(anchor = 'w')
Button(root,text="Ok",command=lambda: [print(selected_users),root.destroy()]).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
from tkinter import *

users=['Anne', 'Bea', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Helen']

class Checkbar(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[]):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.vars = []
      for pick in picks:
         var = IntVar()
         chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick[0], variable=var)
         chk.pack()
         self.vars.append(var)
   def check(self):
    lst=list(map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars))
    nlst=[u for l,u in zip(lst,users) if l==1]
    return nlst

root = Tk()
lng = Checkbar(root, users)
lng.pack()

def allstates(): 
  print(lng.check())
  root.quit()

b=Button(root, text='Check', command=allstates)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What we are doing here is:
We have a list of users in `users` and we create a `check box` using class `Checkbar` and `pack` it in root. Now we have to get the checked names only so, we created the `button`. When we click on that button, it triggers `allstates` function where we are trying to call `Checkbar.check()` function which is returning `list` of `checked button` only. We are doing this by: we have `list` of variables of `checkbutton` variable named as `self.vars`, and using `lambda function` we are trying to get all the button states by doing `<Checkbutton>.get()` and we got list from this like `[0,0,0,1,0]` and But we don't want list like that, we want list of names which is checked. So, we try to check if `anne` is checked or not if checked then add or if not check then go to next for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly more concise way.

Defines `IntVars` in check list

A `Button` to collect results in selected_users.

This version can be reused.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()    

users = [ 'Anne', 'Bea', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Helen' ]
check = []

def select( ):
    global selected_users
    selected_users = []
    for x, n in enumerate( check ):
        selected_users.append( n.get() )
        print( f'{users[ x ]} = {n.get()}' )

for x, n in enumerate( users ):
    check.append( IntVar( root, value = 0 ) )
    l = Checkbutton( root, text = n, variable = check[ x ] )
    l.pack(anchor = 'w')

but = Button( root, text = 'Ok', command = select, width = 20 )
but.pack( fill = 'both')

root.mainloop()
```